# Couchbase high durability

Tags: couchbase, durability

I want to design a banking system using couchbase , and I need high durability (like RDBMS) , How can I achieve 100% durability and not bit of data loss?

[image]

I know I can use `persist_to` and `replicate_to` for durability

```
bucket.insert(id, data, { "persist_to": 3}, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

1- If I have 6 servers and I choose `persist_to=3` , How can I ensure that the data is durable , for instance If the active node is **server1** and my data is persisted to  **server1**, **server2** and **server3** , and we have a fail on **server1** , What if **server4** -that has no data in memory or disk- become active?

2- How can I detect from SDK the size of cluster dynamically?And set `persist_to` to majority (numberOfNodes/2+1)

Comment: There is a limit to the number of replicas that you can have total, and this is defined on the bucket configuration. The maximum is 3. The `persist_to`/`replicate_to` settings are client side checks that will *confirm* that the documents have been persisted/replicated, but it's Couchbase itself that is queuing the replication, not the client.

Comment: @MatthewGroves I know there is a max 3 limit for replicas , Assume this scenario  **server1** is active(master) and **server2**, **server3**, **server4** is replica (slave) for my vBucket , If at the time I change data **server1** failed and changes is propagated to   **server2**, **server3** but not  **server4** what happends if **server4** become active(master) , Do I lost changes? as master (server4) dont accept data from slave (server2 and server3)